# Handling large output values from reduce step in Hadoop

Tags: java, memory, hadoop, mapreduce, stringbuilder

During the Reduce phase of my MapReduce program, the only operation I'm performing is to concatonate each value in the provided Iterator, as below:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<text> values,
                    OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) {
    Text next;
    Text outKey = new Text()
    Text outVal = new Text();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(values.hasNext()) {
        next = values.next();
        sb.append(next.toString());
        if (values.hasNext())
            sb.append(',');
    }
    outKey.set(key.toString());
    outVal.set(sb.toSTring());
    output.collect(outKey,outVal);
}
```

My problem is that some of the reduce output values are *huge* lines of text; so large that even with a very large initial size, the string buffer must increase (double) its size several times to accommodate all of the context of the iterator, causing a memory issue.

In a traditional Java application, this would indicate that a buffered write to a file would be the preferred method of writing output.  How do you handle extremely large output key-value pairs in Hadoop?  Should I stream the results directly to a file on HDFS (one file per reduce call)?  Is there a way to buffer the output, something other than the output.collect method?

Note: I've already increased my memory/heapsize to the maximum extent possible.  Also, several sources have indicated that increasing the number of reducers can help with memory/heap issues, but the issue here has been traced directly to the use of SringBuilder while it is expanding its capacity.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that i understand why you would want to have a huge value, but there is a way you can do this.

If you write your own OutputFormat, you can fix the behaviour of the `RecordWriter.write(Key, Value)` method to handle value concatenation based upon whether the Key value is null or not.

This way, in your reducer, you can write your code as follows (the first output for the key is the actual key, and everything after that is null key:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) {
  boolean firstKey = true;
  for (Text value : values) {
    output.collect(firstKey ? key : null, value);
    firstKey = false;
  }
}
```

The actual `RecordWriter.write()` then has the following logic to handle the null key / value concatenation logic:

```
    public synchronized void write(K key, V value) throws IOException {

        boolean nullKey = key == null || key instanceof NullWritable;
        boolean nullValue = value == null || value instanceof NullWritable;
        if (nullKey && nullValue) {
            return;
        }

        if (!nullKey) {
            // if we've written data before, append a new line
            if (dataWritten) {
                out.write(newline);
            }

            // write out the key and separator
            writeObject(key);
            out.write(keyValueSeparator);
        } else if (!nullValue) {
            // write out the value delimiter
            out.write(valueDelimiter);
        }

        // write out the value
        writeObject(value);

        // track that we've written some data
        dataWritten = true;
    }

    public synchronized void close(Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        // if we've written out any data, append a closing newline
        if (dataWritten) {
            out.write(newline);
        }

        out.close();
    }
```

You'll notice the close method has also been amended to write a trailing newline to the last record written out

Full code listing can be found on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mfpLXsB8), and here's the test output:

```
key1    value1
key2    value1,value2,value3
key3    value1,value2
```

Answer (score 2):

If single output key-value can be bigger then memory it means that standard output mechanism is not suited - since, by inerface design it require passing of key-value pair and not a stream. 
I think simplest solution would be to stream output right to the HDFS file. 
If you have reasons to pass data via output format - I would suggest the following solution:
a) To write to the local temporary dir 
b) To pass the name of the file as a value for the output format.

Probabbly most effective but a bit complicated solution would be usage of the memory mapped file as a buffer. It will be in memory as long as there is enough memory, and, when needed OS will care about efficient spill to the disk.