# How to implement a Java MapReduce that produce output values large then the maximum Heap?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to process a 9 GB CSV File. During the MR it has to do some grouping and produce a special format for a legacy system.

The input file looks like this:

```
AppId;Username;Other Fields like timestamps...
app/10;Mr Foobar;...
app/10;d0x;...
app/10;Mr leet;...
app/110;kr1s;...
app/110;d0x;...
...
```

And the Outputfile is quite simple like this:

```
app/10;3;Mr Foobar;d0x;Mr leet
app/110;2;kr1s;d0x
^       ^ ^^^^^^^^
\ AppId \         \ A list with all users playing the game
         \
          \ Ammount of users
```

To solve that, I wrote a mapper that returns the `AppId` as **Key** and the `Username` as **value**. With this the mapping phase runs fine.

The problem happens on the reduce phase. There I'll get a `Iterator<Text> userIds` that potentially contains a List with a lot of userIds (>5.000.000).

The reducer to process this looks like this:

```
public class UserToAppReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, UserSetWritable> {
    final UserSetWritable   userSet = new UserSetWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(final Text appId, final Iterable<Text> userIds, final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        this.userSet.clear();

        for (final Text userId : userIds) {
            this.userSet.add(userId.toString());

        }
        context.write(appId, this.userSet);
    }   
}
```

The `UserSetWritable` is a custom writable that stores a list of users. This is needed to generate the output (key = appId, value = a list of usernames).

This is how the current `UserSetWritable` looks like:

```
 public class UserSetWritable implements Writable {
    private final Set<String>   userIds = new HashSet<String>();

    public void add(final String userId) {
        this.userIds.add(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(this.userIds.size());

        for (final String userId : this.userIds) {
            out.writeUTF(userId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(final DataInput in) throws IOException {
        final int size = in.readInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.userIds.add(readUTF);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (final String userId : this.userIds) {
            result += userId + "\t";
        }

        result += this.userIds.size();
        return result;
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.userIds.clear();
    }

 }
```

With this approche I get a Java HeapOutOfMemory Exception.

```
Error: Java heap space
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0: WARN : mapreduce.Counters - Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0: WARN : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0: WARN : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - slave.host.name is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.hostname
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0: FATAL: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child - Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.toString(HeapCharBuffer.java:542)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at java.nio.CharBuffer.toString(CharBuffer.java:1157)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:394)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:371)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:273)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at     com.myCompany.UserToAppReducer.reduce(UserToAppReducer.java:21)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at     com.myCompany.UserToAppReducer.reduce(UserToAppReducer.java:1)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
attempt_201303072200_0016_r_000002_0:   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

`UserToAppReducer.java:21` is this line: `this.userSet.add(userId.toString());`

On the same cluster I am able to proccess the data with this pig Script:

```
set job.name convertForLegacy
set default_parallel 4
data = load '/data/...txt' 

using PigStorage(',') 
as (appid:chararray,uid:chararray,...);
grp = group data by appid;
counter = foreach grp generate group, data.uid, COUNT(data);
store counter into '/output/....' using PigStorage(',');
```

So how to solve this OutOfMemoryException with MapReduce?

Comment: Looks like your Pig script doesn't actually function in the same way your Reducer does (is counts the number of users rather than compiling a unique set of them) - which behaviour are you aiming for?

Comment: oh, you are right. I like to have a unique set

Comment: What problem are you trying to solove: how to deduplicate the list of users, or how to fit a very large list of users on a single line? In the first case you should consider secondary sort.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question for writing out 'large' values: [Handling large output values from reduce step in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140171/handling-large-output-values-from-reduce-step-in-hadoop)

In addition to using this concept for writing out large records (getting the CSV list you want of 100,000's of users), you'll need to use a composite key (the App ID and user ID) and custom partitioner to ensure all the keys for a single App ID make their way to the reducer.

Some like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chriswhite199/5121876) (not tested).